Is MuseScore the right tool for neumatic notation?
I am trying to typeset the following:

but I can only get this far:

Am I using the right tool?
I have the feeling that I am not far away, but I can not get the space between the double quarter heads (bipunctum) for the lyric "Got-", or the following heads spaced correctly.
Using a Gregorian-specific tool would feel a bit like overkill.
Note: The double quarters are achieved by x-positioning the second one by -4 or -6 sp.

This is a bit confusing. Judging by the heads this seems to try to mimic modal square notation. But as far as I know there is no ligature of just putting two punctae next to each other. So I’m confused of what this should actually mean? Is this a weird notation or a mora? Where is this from, and do you have any idea what the intent is? And do you insist on notating this in a confusing notation, or might it be actually better to change notation?

It is used for some older chants in german hymnals (EG 190.2) and sung as if it were a half note. I would like to keep this look. sample recording:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfcRc273gyA

A barline set to -7 span would look just like that breath mark. Aside from that, I'd answer "is MuseScore right for this job" with a confident "No."

@Lazy you see this in Latin chant, too, e.g. Ecce advenit dominator Dominus in the Graduale triplex.

@phoog Found it. It is a bistropha, so acually a replication of the note.

@Lazy there is also a school of thought that holds that it simply represents a longer note (as it does in the modern practice described by Stefan Hegny), since it was in use before the development of a system of using different shapes, flags, etc., to indicate different durations.

Using MuseScore 4, make the following adjustments to what you already have:

Remove "Got-tes" and then re-add it, associated only with the first of the "close-together" notes.
Select the note associated with "tes" and use its horizontal offset property to move it closer to the "Got" notes.
Select "Gottes" and drag it so it's aligned correctly with the notes, further adjusting the notes horizontal offsets if needed.



Thank you, seems like it would make sense to upgrade to version 4...

@StefanHegny in v3, I believe you can do the same thing using the element inspector.

At step 2, moving the "-tes" note close, then the distance appears after the -tes and before the "der". It seems I can not find a way to shift everything to the left.

@StefanHegny You could try a couple of things. 1) Play around with the properties in Format -> Style... / Measures. If you set minimum distances (e.g., "Note to barline") to zero, then you can basically control the placement of every note by dragging and/or using the horizontal offset. 2) 63 is the largest number allowed for time signature numerators, but a time signature of 63/1, then setting in very small note values (say, eighth note is the longest) would allow for much if not all of the score to fit in a single measure.

@StefanHegny You might also find https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/early-music-features#unbarred-notation helpful.


Am I using the right tool?

I would use lilypond. The default Gregorian contexts differ from the example in some details, most notably the clef and the use of a four-line staff, but it should be possible to tweak those fairly easily.  As a starting point, I used the example at https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/gregorian-chant-contexts and changed it to this, which seems like it's relatively close to what you want:
\new VaticanaScore {
  <<
    \new VaticanaVoice = "cantus" {
      \key f \major
      f g a a \[ bes\melisma bes\melismaEnd \] a \divisioMinima a g
    }
    \new VaticanaLyrics \lyricsto "cantus" {
      Chri -- ste, du Lamm Got -- tes, der du
    }
  >>
}

You can play around with this at https://hacklily.org but they're still on 2.22, so the there are some small differences; compare https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/gregorian-chant-contexts

As much as I love Lilypond, it's not the right tool for setting most chant for most situations given the alternatives like Illuminare, especially OP's particular example. OP wasn't clear what type of notation they were trying to transcribe to, though.

@Richard Can you add an answer describing Illuminare and its application to these requirements? I said "I would use Lilypond" because, well, I would, but I say that after having used only a handful of notation tools for only a handful of projects, not because of extensive experience. I would also think of Lilypond because of its flexibility, which of course doesn't imply ease of use. On the other hand, I've never heard of Illuminare before now.  Does Illuminare support modern clefs and five-line staves with the "square" puncta style shown in the example?

Not a definitive answer... but as the final target was an inkscape leaflet I decided to export the score you see to pdf, import into inkscape and adjust as necessary, dragging everything that was too far right to the left etc etc.
Thank you all for your thoughts! Used musescore successfully for several different parts or our eucharist liturgy.
Probably "no" is the correct answer, but getting into another tool like tweaking around with lilypond did not seem justified.

